# How recursive methods are called

Tags: java, recursion

I am new to Java. I need to know how this recursive method works and how it is called.

Why is "I AM FROM Y" printed 2 times?

**Caller**    :    z(3);

**Calling Method**

```
public void z(int i){

            int y=i;
            System.out.println("I am from Z");
            if(y<5){
                z(++i);
                System.out.println("I AM FROM Y");
            }

        }
```

**output**:

> ```
>     I am from Z
>     I am from Z
>     I am from Z
>     I AM FROM Y
>     I AM FROM Y
> ```

Comment: I think you need to read up on [what exactly recursion is](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion) (and not specifically just in Java).

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24640181) for enlightenment on how recursion works.

Answer (score 3):

Let's trace the recursive calls.

```
z(3) is called.
  Prints "I am from Z"
  y is 3 and y < 5: "if" is entered.
  z(4) is called.
    Prints "I am from Z"
    y is 4 and y < 5: "if" is entered.
    z(5) is called.
      Prints "I am from Z"
      y is 5 and "if" is NOT entered.  This recursive call ends.
    Prints "I AM FROM Y".  This recursive call ends.
  Prints "I AM FROM Y".  This recursive call ends.
```

"I AM FROM Y" is printed twice, once each by the "z(4)" method invocation and the "z(3)" method invocation, but not by the "z(5)" method invocation.

Answer (score 0):

- from the code, "I am from Z" is printed unconditionally each time the function is called recursively hence it is printed thrice but "I am from Y" is only printed twice because on the third call, the value of i does not satisfy the if condition:
- During the first call  of z (i==3) execution will get into the if condition because i<5 (3 is less than 5)
- This leads to the second call of z with i incremented to 4; again the if condition succeeds because 4 is less than five
- On the third call, i has been incremented to 5 (5 !< 5) so it won't enter the if condition.
- Hence the third call returns WITHOUT printing "I am from Y"
- But the second and first call subsequently return after printing "I am from Y" respectively

Answer (score 0):

I will simplify your method a little since in this scenario  `y` can be replaced with `i`

```
public static void z(int i) {
    System.out.println("I am from Z");
    if (i < 5) {
        z(++i);
        System.out.println("I AM FROM Y");
    }
}
```

As you see this method will call another `z(++i)` recursively only if `i` will be less than `5`. Also `I am from Z` is mandatory (there is no condition which stops it from printing), but `I AM FROM Y` is optional (it depends on result of `i < 5`, just like recursive call).

In other words last recursive call (the one which will not call another `z(++i)` because `i` *will not be lesser* than `5`) will also not print `I AM FROM Y`.
This means that `I am from Z` will always be printed on more time than `I am from Y`.

You can visualize it this way

```
I am from Z -------> z(3) 
 I am from Z ------> z(4) 
  I am from Z -----> z(5) here `i` is `5` so no `I AM FROM Y` will be printed 
 I AM FROM Y ------> z(4)
I AM FROM Y -------> z(3)
```

which leaves you `I am from Z` printed three times, and `I AM FROM Y` two times.